# choosing table collation for universal characters

Tags: mysql, mariadb, collation

I'm working on a backend that needs to store universal characters.

I've chosen `utf8mb4` Table Encoding for that purpose. I also have to choose Table Collation.

The most straightforward option is to choose `utf8mb4_general_ci` Table collation. Besides the general one, there is also about 20 others collations to choose from.. What is the purpose of the more specific ones? Does `utf8mb4_general_ci` or maybe `utf8mb4_unicode520_ci` cover all of them? Which one should I use if I want to store characters ranging from chinese all the way to arab.

Comment: Check the answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38363566/trouble-with-utf-8-characters-what-i-see-is-not-what-i-stored

Answer (score 2):

- `...general_ci` is simple.  It does not equate 2-character combinations (such as with a non-spacing mark) with the single-character equivalent.
- `...unicode_520_ci` comes from Unicode version 5.20, the latest version available when MySQL picked up on it.  It handles things like having an ordering for Emoji, which previous versions did not have.
- With MySQL 8.0, the preferred collation is `utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci`, based on Unicode 9.0.
- `...<language>_ci` handles variations found in the given language.  For example, should `ch` and `ll` in Spanish be treated as "letters" and sort between `cz` and `d`, and `lz` and `m`.
- For general use, do not use `...general_ci`, use the latest version derived from Unicode.  For language-specific situations, pick one of the other collations.
- I do know know how (or even whether) Chinese and Arabic are sorted differently in the different collations.  However, I see `...persion_ci`, so I suspect there is an issue.
- Do use `utf8mb4`, not `utf8`, especially since you need Chinese.